# "Unable to create Maven project from repository."

Tags: java, maven

I'm currently getting this error doing `Maven Site`:

```
Unable to create Maven project from repository.
```

My configuration:

```
<url>grocery.com</url>
<distributionManagement>
   <repository>
        <id>grocery</id>
        <url>grocery.com</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

As far as I understand Maven Site, at the end of the process, it should pop a report website link and this link would work locally. So, I can use any url or do I need a specific one?

Here is the full `bug report`:

- https://codeshare.io/5XbJe8

My complete `pom.xml`:

- https://codeshare.io/ad0nr4

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow you. Could you please explain in more detail what you want? Do you want to create a Maven Site locallly and open it? Then just run `mvn site`.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Hi! That's what I'm doing but I get this error that came from my `distributionManagement` configuration, I think.

Comment: The command `mvn site` does not distribute anything. Please post the POM and the complete error (in the question, not in the comments).

Comment: Are you sure this is the POM for the output? The error does not seem to make sense for that POM.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Yes, I'm sure! I just replaced a word in all paths containing private informations but that's the output from it.

Comment: 1/X Fix please this error: `[ERROR] 'distributionManagement.status' must not be specified. @ line 182, column 13` .... Second upgrade the project info reports plugin to the most recent version. If you like to run integration test run them via maven-failsafe-plugin and not via surefire plugin. Remove the dependency to the plugin for junit-platform...

Comment: Remove the dependencies to maven plugins (surefire, jacoco) which is simply wrong...*NOTE*: And most important run the build on plain command line and from within IntelliJ... just plain command line: `mvn site` ... that will printout some errors/warnings but that's a different story...

Comment: @khmarbaise `[ERROR] 'distributionManagement.status' must not be specified.` was solved by putting up to date the version of ` project info reports plugin` to `3.1.1` and the whole thing worked! I'll apply the rest of your advices. Thank you so much!